# Alternative for Meeting WorkSpace for O365 SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, wss-3.0, meeting-workspace

This is the challenge I am facing while migrating from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Online. I know that Meeting Workspace are deprecated in SharePoint 2013. There are certain articles of enabling this template using 15 hive. [Enable meeting Workspace](http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/make-meeting-workspaces-available-in-sharepoint-2013/)

But how can I do the same in SharePoint online? OR is there any way I can get same experience as meeting Workspace for SP Online by using custom solution.
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For moving to SharePoint Online, I would convert the meeting spaces to Office 365 groups and migrate the desired content to the group space. I would recommend a migration tool to assist with this process.

So for a migration approach, you would first need to [create a Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Office-365-Group-in-the-admin-center-74a1ef8b-3844-4d08-9980-9f8f7a36000f) in Office 365. Once the group is created, you'd need to use a migration tool like those offered from ShareGate, Metalogix, etc. You connect to both sites in the tool and migrate content from the meeting work space to the newly created group.

Comment: Meeting space is a site so how can I convert this to O365 groups. Can u please provide more details on this

Comment: Thank you for the update, Surely I will take hep from 3rd party tools. But wouldn't the tool will create O365 group for me as a part of migration? what say!

Comment: At this point, they may have the capability built into the tools. If so then yes the tool could help you there. Otherwise you could do it through the UI or bulk create what you need via PowerShell.

Comment: @EricAlexander, I am not able to understand how this office 365 group will help in achieving functionality of meeting workspace in SP Online?