# How to enable Meeting workspace Template in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to enable the meeting workspace template in SharePoint Online. I dont need workaround but just trying to see if there is a way to enable the template in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

No, there are only a couple of "classic" templates available. WYSIWYG with regards to available templates. You can extend Modern Team/Comm sites with Site Designs.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned site template has been deprecated and not available ever since SharePoint 2013.

To use similar experience in SharePoint Online, you may use Site Design as Trevor suggests, or refer to the posts here for ideas on alternative solutions:

[Alternative for Meeting WorkSpace for O365 SharePoint Online.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220108/alternative-for-meeting-workspace-for-o365-sharepoint-online)

[How to build an alternative to Meeting Workspaces in SharePoint 2013.](https://collab365.community/the-alternative-for-meeting-workspaces-in-sharepoint-2013/)